# Why itoa fuction returns 32 bits if the size of variable in 16 bit

Tags: c, binary, bit, low-level

Size of short int is 2 bytes (16 bits) on my 64 bit processor and mingw compiler but when I convert short int variable to a binary string using itoa function, it returns string of 32 bits:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char buffer [50];
short int a=-2;
itoa(a,buffer,2); //converting a to binary

printf("%s %d",buffer,sizeof(a));
}
```

Output

```
11111111111111111111111111111110 2
```

Comment: *Sign extension* when the `short int` is converted to `int`. Because the `itoa` function wants an `int` as argument.

Comment: Perhaps `itoa(a & USHRT_MAX, buffer, 2);`

Comment: @Usama If code was `int a=-2; itoa(a,buffer,2); rintf("%s",buffer);`, would you expect `"11111111111111111111111111111110"`, `"-10`" or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in understanding C's promotion of `short` datatypes (and `char`'s, too!) to `int`'s when those values are used as parameters passed to a function **and** understanding the consequences of *sign extension*.

This may be more understandable with a very simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf( "%08X  %08X\n", (unsigned)(-2), (unsigned short)(-2));
    // Both are cast to 'unsigned' to avoid UB

    return 0;
}
/* Prints:
FFFFFFFE  0000FFFE
*/
```

Both parameters to `printf()` were, as usual, *promoted* to 32 bit `int`'s. The left hand value **is** -2 (decimal) in 32bit notation. By using the cast to specify the other parameter should not be subjected to sign extension, the printed value shows that it was treated as a 32 bit representation of the original 16 bit `short`.

`itoa()` is not available in my compiler for testing, but this should give the expected results

```
itoa( (unsigned short)a, buffer, 2 );
```

Comment: Note that `printf( "%08X", -2);` is UB.  Often a nice UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you, again... I hope this edit improves the answer. Grew up in the wild west, where UB feared for its own life... `:-)`

Comment: It does improve, yet `itoa()` is itself non-standard and its result with a negative `int` via base 2 is unclear.

Comment: Unlike `printf`, passing args to `itoa` doesn't apply the "usual integer promotions" (where all narrow types are promoted to `int`).  Because `itoa` has a prototype.  The argument is explicitly declared to be `int`, so that's what the compiler promotes to.  But it could have been declared `short`, although then you'd expect it to be called `stoa` or something.  So printf is useful for printing in a different base, and for a portable example for systems without an exported itoa, but not as a correct explanation of why promotion happens for itoa's arg.  It just happens to be the same promotion.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is so simple , refer to [itoa() manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=functions-itoa-convert-int-into-string) , you will notice its prototype which is

> char * itoa(int n, char * buffer, int radix);

so it takes an `int` that to be converted and you are passing a `short int` so it's converted from **2 byte** width to **4 byte** width , that's why it's printing a 32 bits.

**to solve this problem :**
you can simply shift left the array by 16 position by the following simple `for loop` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
    buffer[i] = buffer[i+16];
}
```

and it shall give the same result , here is edited version of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char buffer [50];
    short int a= -2;
    itoa(a,buffer,2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 17; ++i) {
        buffer[i] = buffer[i+16];
    }

    printf("%s %d",buffer,sizeof(a));
}
```

and this is the output:

```
1111111111111110 2
```

Comment: [refer to itoa() manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=functions-itoa-convert-int-into-string) link does not support base == 2.

Comment: @chux But since `itoa` is a nonstandard function, there's no one manual to refer to.  [Here's one](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) that says the base can be anything from 2 to 36, which is certainly the definition I'm more familiar with.  (But I've also seen libraries with two-argument `itoa` functions, that don't take a base at all.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I agree about the possibilities with `itoa()`, yet the answer here references a limited `itoa()` that does not support base 2. 
 OP is looking for a base 2 answer, hence the comment.